# Corporeal - spelling over time

Tags: english, words

Note the English phrase 'Corporal Punishment'. I suspect that it is a spelling corruption of Corporeal. I haven't been able to find any information on this online.

Is this just a rule of spelling I'm unaware of, or otherwise, when did this corruption first happen? Can you also point me to other posts discussing matters of similarity?

Comment: I guess this question is better placed at [elu.se].

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/411065

Answer (score 2):

It seems more likely that this is from Latin *corporālis*, which is the same suffix as in e.g. *liminal* (for which there is no **limineal*). You can use Wiktionary for things like this.